Why doesn’t HP 250 G8 Notebook PC (7N0M2ES) Windows 11 want to sign in?
Laptop does not want to sign in, after boot, I get to sign in screen, click on "sign in" and then I get "just a moments that loads forever, I never get to desktop.
I haven't updated anything, this started yesterday, and 2 days ago it was just fine.
Using the recovery environments command prompt, I tried sfc/scannow and it said it repaired the corrupted files and reboot and stuff, but after reboot same thing, when I tried DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth and I also tried the ScanHealth (I changed RestoreHealth to ScanHealth), it didn't work, says "the cleanup-image option is unknown".

Could you explain how you ran SFC and DISM if you're not able to login to the computer? Also, what is the full command for DISM Cleanup-Image? Please add this information to your question using the EDIT button. Finally, add information about what led up to this problem occurring for the first time.

Notification of changes
